# Remove title at the top from Bottom Tabs Navigation React Navigation Native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

[image]

How do i remove this from the screen, I'm using Bottom Tabs and it is automatically showing

```
`<View style={{ height: "100%" }}>
  <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{ headerTitle: false }}
    initialRouteName="home"
    tabBar={(props) => <BottomNavigator {...props} />}
  >
    <Tab.Screen name="cash" component={Savings} />
    <Tab.Screen name="bar-chart" component={Statistics} />
    <Tab.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
    <Tab.Screen name="card" component={Budgeting} />
    <Tab.Screen name="person" component={Profile} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</View>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `headerShown: false` in `screenOptions`:

```
<View style={{ height: "100%" }}>
  <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
    }}
    initialRouteName="home"
    tabBar={(props) => <BottomNavigator {...props} />}
  >
    <Tab.Screen name="cash" component={Savings} />
    <Tab.Screen name="bar-chart" component={Statistics} />
    <Tab.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
    <Tab.Screen name="card" component={Budgeting} />
    <Tab.Screen name="person" component={Profile} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</View>
```